# Retrieving sibling with xsl:key

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a table schema which has some meta field data which I need to pull down to the row level.

So this ...

```xml
<tables>
    <table name="T01">
        <columns>
            <column name="F01">
                <heading>Field 1</heading>
            </column >
            <column name="F02">
                <heading>Field 2</heading>
            </column>
        </columns>
        <rows>
            <row>
                <field name="F01">AAAAA</field>
                <field name="F02">BBBBB</field>
            </row>
            <row>
                <field name="F01">DDDDD</field>
                <field name="F02">EEEEE</field>
            </row>
        </rows>
    </table>
    <table name="T02">
        <!-- ... -->
    </table>
</tables>
```

should become this ...

```xml
<tables>
    <table name="T01">
        <rows>
            <row>
                <field name="F01">
                    <heading>Field 1</heading>
                    <value>AAAAA</value>
                </field>
                <field name="F02">                    
                    <heading>Field 2</heading>  
                    <value>BBBBB</value>
                </field>
            </row>
            <row>
                <field name="F01">
                    <heading>Field 1</heading>
                    <value>DDDDD</value>
                </field>
                <field name="F02">                    
                    <heading>Field 2</heading>  
                    <value>EEEEE</value>
                </field>
            </row>
        </rows>
    </table>
    <table name="T02">
        <!-- ... -->
    </table>
</tables>
```

I am sure there are tons of *simple* ways to do this with XSLT, but due to my tool, I really need to retrieve the column heading via a key(). So something like this ...

```xsl
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- This won't work but if it did ... -->
  <xsl:key name="field-heading"
          match="../../columns/column/heading"
          use="../@name" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="field">
    <field name="{@name}">
      <heading>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('field-heading', @name)"/>
      </heading>
      <value>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </value>
    </field>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="columns"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But the xsl:key match attribute doesn't allow the parent axis and I am not sure if there are any other ways make it fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A slightly simpler solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kColByNames" match="column" use=
  "concat(../../@name, '+', @name)"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="field">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
   <heading>
     <xsl:value-of select=
      "key('kColByNames', concat(ancestor::table[1]/@name, '+', @name))"/>
   </heading>
   <value><xsl:value-of select="."/></value>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="columns"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<tables>
    <table name="T01">
        <columns>
            <column name="F01">
                <heading>Field 1</heading>
            </column>
            <column name="F02">
                <heading>Field 2</heading>
            </column>
        </columns>
        <rows>
            <row>
                <field name="F01">AAAAA</field>
                <field name="F02">BBBBB</field>
            </row>
            <row>
                <field name="F01">DDDDD</field>
                <field name="F02">EEEEE</field>
            </row>
        </rows>
    </table>
    <table name="T02">
        <!-- ... -->
    </table>
</tables>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<tables>
   <table name="T01">
      <rows>
         <row>
            <field name="F01">
               <heading>Field 1</heading>
               <value>AAAAA</value>
            </field>
            <field name="F02">
               <heading>Field 2</heading>
               <value>BBBBB</value>
            </field>
         </row>
         <row>
            <field name="F01">
               <heading>Field 1</heading>
               <value>DDDDD</value>
            </field>
            <field name="F02">
               <heading>Field 2</heading>
               <value>EEEEE</value>
            </field>
         </row>
      </rows>
   </table>
   <table name="T02"><!-- ... --></table>
</tables>
```

**Explanation**: Overriding the identity rule and using a composite key -- a `column` is identified by the *pair* of its `name` attribute and the `name` attribute of its grandparent `table`.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that the context for the key definition is the document not the place where you use the key so the definition should be

```
<xsl:key name="field-heading"
    match="/tables/table/columns/column/heading"
    use="../@name" />
```

There are a couple of typos in your XML - this is what I think it should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="C:/Users/morank/Documents/temp/code.xsl"?>
<tables>
    <table name="T01">
        <columns>
            <column name="F01">
                <heading>Field 1</heading>
            </column>
            <column name="F02">
                <heading>Field 2</heading>
            </column>
        </columns>
        <rows>
            <row>
                <field name="F01">AAAAA</field>
                <field name="F02">BBBBB</field>
            </row>
            <row>
                <field name="F01">DDDDD</field>
                <field name="F02">EEEEE</field>
            </row>
        </rows>
    </table>
    <table name="T02">
        <!-- ... -->
    </table>
</tables>
```

Applying the following XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- This won't work but if it did ... -->
    <xsl:key name="field-heading"
        match="/tables/table/columns/column/heading"
        use="../@name" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="field">
        <field name='{@name}'>
            <heading>
                <xsl:value-of select="key('field-heading', @name)"/>
            </heading>
            <value>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </value>
        </field>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="columns"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Gives the desired output of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="C:/Users/morank/Documents/temp/code.xsl"?><tables>
    <table name="T01">        
        <rows>
            <row>
                <field name="F01">
                    <heading>Field 1</heading>
                    <value>AAAAA</value>
                </field>
                <field name="F02">
                    <heading>Field 2</heading>
                    <value>BBBBB</value>
                </field>
            </row>
            <row>
                <field name="F01">
                    <heading>Field 1</heading>
                    <value>DDDDD</value>
                </field>
                <field name="F02">
                    <heading>Field 2</heading>
                    <value>EEEEE</value>
                </field>
            </row>
        </rows>
    </table>
    <table name="T02">
        <!-- ... -->
    </table>
</tables>
```

Note that I also changed the template to be the standard identity transform and made sure that the field's name was copied

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<xsl:key name="field-heading"
    match="heading"
    use="parent::column/@name" />
```

In this case, `../` won't work because the `use` path isn't starting from root.

---

**EDIT**

Try creating the key using the `table/@name` along with the `column/@name`. This should make it unique.

**XML Input** (I hope this represents the issue from your comment.)

```
<tables>
  <table name="T01">
    <columns>
      <column name="F01">
        <heading>Field 1</heading>
      </column>
      <column name="F02">
        <heading>Field 2</heading>
      </column>
    </columns>
    <rows>
      <row>
        <field name="F01">AAAAA</field>
        <field name="F02">BBBBB</field>
      </row>
      <row>
        <field name="F01">DDDDD</field>
        <field name="F02">EEEEE</field>
      </row>
    </rows>
  </table>
  <table name="T02">
    <columns>
      <column name="F01">
        <heading>Field A</heading>
      </column>
      <column name="F02">
        <heading>Field B</heading>
      </column>
    </columns>
    <rows>
      <row>
        <field name="F01">11111</field>
        <field name="F02">22222</field>
      </row>
      <row>
        <field name="F01">44444</field>
        <field name="F02">55555</field>
      </row>
    </rows>
  </table>
</tables>
```

**Modified XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!-- This won't work but if it did ... -->
  <xsl:key name="field-heading"
    match="heading"
    use="concat(ancestor::table/@name,'+',parent::column/@name)" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="field">
    <field name="{@name}">
      <heading>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('field-heading', concat(ancestor::table/@name,'+',@name))"/>
      </heading>
      <value>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </value>
    </field>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="columns"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<tables>
  <table name="T01">

      <rows>
         <row>
            <field name="F01">
               <heading>Field 1</heading>
               <value>AAAAA</value>
            </field>
            <field name="F02">
               <heading>Field 2</heading>
               <value>BBBBB</value>
            </field>
         </row>
         <row>
            <field name="F01">
               <heading>Field 1</heading>
               <value>DDDDD</value>
            </field>
            <field name="F02">
               <heading>Field 2</heading>
               <value>EEEEE</value>
            </field>
         </row>
      </rows>
  </table>
  <table name="T02">

      <rows>
         <row>
            <field name="F01">
               <heading>Field A</heading>
               <value>11111</value>
            </field>
            <field name="F02">
               <heading>Field B</heading>
               <value>22222</value>
            </field>
         </row>
         <row>
            <field name="F01">
               <heading>Field A</heading>
               <value>44444</value>
            </field>
            <field name="F02">
               <heading>Field B</heading>
               <value>55555</value>
            </field>
         </row>
      </rows>
  </table>
</tables>
```

Comment: This will work _but_ only if the column/field names are unique across all the tables or at least share the same heading text. I am leading towards just insuring/assuming the later. But not quite what I am hoping for

Comment: @ryse - I hope I understand the issue correctly. Please take a look at my edit and let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I think that this is about the closest I can get. I was really hoping that won't have change the `use` to have anything other than the column/field name but that square peg of wish just doesn't seem to fit in round hole of XSLT.